# Stanford NER - MISC Entity?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford NER and I have some results with the entity "MISC" in the

```
4 class :Location, Person, Organization, Misc
```

but I don't know what really represent this entity, anyone know what is that entity ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

MISC is a category from the CoNLL 2003 evaluation data which is typically used to develop NER models.  Honestly I don't think there is any definition of MISC beyond "is a named entity" and "isn't PERSON, ORG, or LOC".

Comment: Ok, so this entity is "useless" if we can't define what it represent ?

Comment: If you are interested in cars, the fact that you found an Audi Quattro T3 may well be useful information even though it's not in one of the three main categories.

Answer (score 4):

I found this description on spaCy:
"MISC: Miscellaneous entities, e.g., events, nationalities, products, or works of art."
for models recognizing PER, LOC, ORG, MISC.